# What can cause git commit to disappear?

Tags: git, rebase, sha

With git, I know that rebasing will recreate the commits that are being rebased, thus creating completely new `sha` values for each commit.

Is rebasing the only way to destroy existing `sha` values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it as well which are not described here as well.

- ***`checkout / revert /reflog / reset`***
  Read it all here: [How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)
- ***`git filter-branch`***
  This command alter your history and allow you to delete commits as well.
- ***`git rebase / git rebase -i HEAD~x`***
  Here you can squash several commits into a new commit
- ***`BFG Repo-Cleaner`*** Removes large or troublesome blobs like git-filter-branch does, but faster.

[BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)